# Visual Studio c++ Windows Application: LINK1561 error: entry point must be defined

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli, entry-point

I'm trying to create a windows application. I created New Project->CLR Empty Project. Then I added a form from Project->Add New Item->UI->Windows Form which I named "MainForm". Then I edited MainForm.cpp to contain this following piece of code:

```
#include "MainForm.h"
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
[STAThread]
void main(array<String^>^ args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    FracGen::MainForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);
}
```

(FracGen is the project name)

Then in the Project Properties I set System->SubSystem to `Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)` and in the Advanced Tab I set Entry Point to `main`. However when I try to compile the whole project, I get the LINK1561 error. I tried changing the Entry Point to Main, WinMain, wmain, wMain, ...basically everything suggested on the internet to no avail. What's the catch with this entry point thing? Thanks.

Comment: The error is actually **LNK1561** (not L**I**NK), and there are [many existing questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=LNK1561) regarding this error. Please spend some time reading through those to see if one of them can help. Your definition of `void main(array<String^>^ args)` is also not a valid entry point for either a terminal or Windows program. Google finds the [proper definition of WinMain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381406(v=vs.85).aspx) in less than half a second.

Comment: hello, I took it from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QCnyqMWPkQk I will definitely check your suggestion, but how come it works for the guy from the video? o.O